# Как провалидировать input mask react, что ввели все значения в маску?

Tags: reactjs

```
import React from 'react';
import InputElement from 'react-input-mask';
import { Form, FormGroup, Label, Input, Button } from 'reactstrap';

export default class App extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        password: '',
        phone: '',
        disabled: true
    };

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
}

handleChange(e, inputName) {
    switch (inputName) {
        case 'password':
            if(e.target.value.length > 5){
                this.setState({
                    password: true
                });
            }
            break;
        case 'phone':
            console.log(this.state.phone);
                this.setState({
                    phone: true
                });
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    if(this.state.password === true && this.state.phone === true){
        this.setState({
            disabled: false
        });
    }
}

handleSubmit(event) {
    alert('true');
    event.preventDefault();
}

render() {
    return (
        <Form>
            <FormGroup>
                <Label for="examplePassword">Password</Label>
                <Input type="password"  onChange={e => this.handleChange(e,'password')} placeholder="password" />
            </FormGroup>
            <FormGroup>
                <InputElement className="form-control"  mask="+7 (999) 999-99-99" onChange={e => this.handleChange(e,'phone')}  placeholder="phone"/>
            </FormGroup>
            <Button color="primary" onClick={this.handleSubmit} disabled={this.state.disabled}>Submit</Button>
        </Form>
    );
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Укажите **ref** на компоненте **InputElement**

```
InputElement className="form-control"  mask="+7 (999) 999-99-99" onChange={e => this.handleChange(e,'phone')}  placeholder="phone" ref="phone"/>
```

а при валидации берите этот компонент по **ref** и доставайте у него значение

```
let value = this.refs.phone.value;
```

или из состояния

```
let value = this.refs.phone.state.value;
```

И тут уже проверяйте...